# BufferedSource to file - can it be enhanced (parallel etc)

Tags: java, scala

I wonder if i can enhance this code that get BufferedSource and try to iterate it into a file:

```
def saveLocal(filename: String, fileBuffer: BufferedSource, folderName: String) = {
  val path = Paths.get(folderName, filename)
  Some(new PrintWriter(path.toString)).foreach {
    p => {
      fileBuffer.foreach(b=>
      {
        p.write(b)
      })
      p.close
      fileBuffer.close
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason to use `Some(new PrintWriter(path.toString))`? `new` operator never returns `null`. Maybe you wanted to use `scala.util.Try`? Also if an exception will be thrown during writing, you will not close 
 PrintWriter and BufferedSource.

Here how it can be improved:

```
import java.io._
import scala.io.Source

val bufferSize: Int = 10 * 1024

val inPath: String = "/tmp/file_in"
val outPath: String = "/tmp/file_out"

copyFile(inPath, outPath)

def copyFile(inPath: String, outPath: String): Unit = {
  val fsInStream: InputStream = new FileInputStream(inPath)
  val source: Source = Source.createBufferedSource(new FileInputStream(inPath), bufferSize)

  // Two try finally blocks to make sure that writer and fsInStream will be closed,
  // even if an exception will be thrown
  try {
    val writer: Writer = new PrintWriter(outPath)
    try {
      copy(source, writer)
    }
    finally {
      // We don't care about exception during closing, so put it in Try()
      Try(writer.close())
    }
  }
  finally {
    // We don't care about exception during closing, so put it in Try()
    Try(fsInStream.close())
  }
}

def copy(source: Source, writer: Writer): Unit = {
  source.foreach { b =>
    writer.write(b)
  }
}
```